# Accessing checked layers in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, table-of-contents

`qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()` accesses the current active layer, but I would like to get all checked layers in the QGIS ToC.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be enough:

```
iface.mapCanvas().layers()
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case `qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()` return the last selected one. To obtain selected layers use the ability of the TreeView that contain the layer list.
More directly:

`iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()`

more detail exploring the class QgsLayerTreeView:

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html

obviously this work after legend refactoring => qgis >= 2.6

Comment: I tried `layers = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeRoot().selectedLayers()` but I get en error "QgisInterface object has no attribute layerTreeRoot"

Comment: sorry I erroneously wrote the wrong method... it is layerTreeView  that can be simply read from QgisInterface documentation.

Comment: Sorry I actually meant the layers that were checked (not selected). I apologize for being unclear in the question - is there a method that gets the layers with checked boxes?